# Add Font Awesome icon after <hr> using CSS

Tags: css, font-awesome

I'm looking to style a Horizontal Rule with CSS. I've done this so far:

http://tinkerbin.com/vdzgAZ9q

However, I want to use the 'icon-star' from [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) instead of the `§` symbol.

Could someone tell me how this would be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Just create a `@font-face` in CSS and set the `Font-Family` on the `hr`.

Comment: Please use JS fiddle instead. And what have you tried? Font Awesome has all the instructions you need to use their font.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First step is download fonts from **[fortawesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/)**
Second include them in to css. **Be careful with the paths to the font files**:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.0.1');
  src: url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.0.1') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.0.1') format('woff'),
    url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.0.1') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

And at last, replace content rule for hr selectior from "§" to "\f005"

```
hr:after { content: "\f005";}
```

Comment: @Rahul All of they can be found after the 274 line in the 'font-awesome.css'

Comment: Thank you so much! I was stumped over the "\f005" part.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `hr` element at all.

There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Qc6J4/